# Detect memory reading and change variable?

Tags: c#, security, memory

I have a simple Console application with the variable X = 10. I then have a loop which asks the user to change the variable and output. I attach a debugger and edit the memory region of my program to change the variable X. What can I do to prevent the user from editing this X variable with a memory editor and also is there anyway of detecting(in my program) debuggers or memory editors such that when variable X is accessed move variable X somewhere else and when variable X is changed send a message to the user that you shouldn't be doing that? This is just an educational experiment of mine.

For example in the code below

```
        byte X = 10;
        X = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // scan memory looking for X to change
        Console.ReadKey(); // Change X before the output
        Console.WriteLine("X = " + X);
```

X can easily be edited before the program outputs and even with a couple other fancy pointer tricks it can still be edited easily before the output with a simple external program.

Comment: Please could you post the code, code is always more understandable then only words

Comment: @CuongLe I thought about uploading the code but really this is such an abstract question. Basically it is a concept that could carry across to any program. All I have is a simple program with a single variable and I use an external program to change the memory of that variable to whatever I want. But it is so easy to change the memory value there must be some way of securing(99%) the memory from the user. Edit: Added some code to give my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Fundamentally if you've got a user with enough access that they can poke around in another process's memory, there's not a lot you can do.

This is very rarely an issue in my experience, however.

If it's *really* a problem in your case, you could potentially reduce the attack space by only maintaining values in an encrypted form - then have a "working space" for unencrypted data, which is only trusted *immediately* after decryption, and wiped after use. It doesn't completely eradicate the attack vector, but it could reduce it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an easy way to encrypt most variables in a program this way? Would each variable end up having to be a class?

Comment: @CodeCamper: No, because there *is* no easy way. What I've described would be ludicrously over the top for "most variables" in a program. It's simply not a good idea. You might *very occasionally* do it for very sensitive data (which is why the `SecureString` class exists, for example) but it's really rare.

Comment: In some programs such as Flash it appears as though variables are all encrypted or jumbling around this way preventing the sort of memory editing I am worried about. Is that just a fundamental difference?

Comment: @CodeCamper: I know nothing about Flash... but objects can move around in memory in .NET too, as part of GC compaction.